# How can I modify my Python code to properly identify busy restaurants in DoorDash for a specific location?

Tags: python

Getting Valid Code Doordash is not busy  but it is busy; I am using python
im trying to get the deliever app to connect to a messagin service and when it lights up in red and alerts me thats is busy in that area.

but i keep getting area not busy even though the area is busy im new to programming please take look at my code

```
import requests
import json

# Set up the API endpoint
url = "https://api.doordash.com/v2/"

# Set up the headers
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "69613440-d249-4a70-a087-d32e0a43f386"
}

# Send the request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the response JSON
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    # Check the Dasher status
    if data["is_active"]:
        print("You can start dashing now!")
    else:
        print("You cannot start dashing at the moment.")
else:
    print("Error: Could not retrieve Dasher status.")
```

Comment: Is that Authorization value one of your credentials? If so, remove it from the post. It will still be available in the edit history unfortunately, but it will be less likely to be noticed and exploited.

Comment: Which endpoint are you trying to access? `https://api.doordash.com/v2/` appears to be just the base URL. Another potential issue is that your Authorization header is way off. I'm unfamiliar with the DoorDash API but looking at the documentation the auth is supposed to be a JWT. You also mention "area not busy" but there's no code that produces this output. It looks like there are a lot of issues here and a lot of missing details.